# DB4O close() wipe the DB?

Tags: android, database, db4o, object-persistence

I'm using db4o to store different objects in an android application. I get json contents from a sever then them into Objects (contacts here) that I store in a db4o file.

```
ObjectContainer mainDB = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(dbConfig(), DB_MAIN);
mainDB.store(aContact);
```

Now if I directly make a query to get them back from the DB, it works.

```
try {
ObjectSet<Contact> result = db.queryByExample(Contact.class);
contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can loop on the arraylist and the contacts are there, I can print their names and other fiels. But now if I close de db :

```
mainDB.close();
```

If I reopen it with the same code, there's nothing inside anymore, contacts.size() returns 0.
What's wrong? Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you running in an emulator? What does DB_MAIN looks like? How does your configuration (dbConfig()) looks like?. This usually happens when db4o is able to find the database file and initializes a new one.

Comment: is that link related? http://developer.db4o.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/10178/Default.aspx

Comment: I run on both emulator and nexus one. I have this field for the location of the DB : 
public final static String DB_MAIN = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/circusMain.db4o";
and here's the dbConfig() :

Comment: and here's the dbConfig() : 

private EmbeddedConfiguration dbConfig() {
EmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
configuration.common().objectClass(Model.class).objectField("id").indexed(true);
configuration.common().objectClass(Contact.class).objectField("name").indexed(true);
//other objectField configuration for Tasks, Activities and Opportunities
return configuration;
}

Comment: @ened: I don't use the TransparentPersistentSupport like it's done in that link.

Answer (score 1):

If you try a SODA query rather than querybyexample it works?

Answer (score 0):

What's the result of Environment.getExternalStorageState()?
There might be a problem with the dir.
What happens if you try Context.getExternalFilesDir() as directory or getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()?

What happens if you use this dir when opening the container?

ctx.getDir("data", 0) + "/" + "db.file";

where ctx is the app context.