# db4o multiple store() and one close() doesn't work?

Tags: android, db4o, object-persistence

Hi 
I'm using db4o in an android application.
I want to store multiple objects in a database so I have a loop that adds my objects in the db but if I don't put the close() IN the loop (after each store()), all the objects won't persist the next time I open the db. How is this possible? And how can I put only one close() AFTER the loop without having that problem?

I want to do only one close() because this is expensive in IO and it slows down the application initialization on the phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, is this related to [DB4O close() wipe the DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256970/db4o-close-wipe-the-db) ?

This definitely works :)

Can you provide a sample android project that reproduces the problem? (you can email me directly: adriano db4o dot com)

Best

Comment: Indeed it's related to my first problem. I found that if I put a close() after each store(), the objects stay in the db. But it slows down the application a lot :(
I'll make a little project that reproduce the problem and send it to you probably tonight :)

Comment: Jafar, did you managed to create a sample project? Maybe you have sent it to me and it ended up in my spam box.